# Can the use of YLProgressBar added on an alert view cause rejection of my app on app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, uialertview, appstore-approval, alertview

In my iOS application I have used alert view to show a message of 'Loading Data...' and have added a [YLProgressBar](https://github.com/YannickL/YLProgressBar) as a sub view on alert view which shows the progress of data loading process.

I wonder will this approach be acceptable by Apple as I have gone through situations where Apple rejects the app in which a text field is added on alert view. Any reference which gives clarification about this rule is most welcome.

Comment: `UIAlertView` is not designed to have arbitrary subviews added to it. Many people do it and it may work at the moment. But the API for `UIAlertView` is to show a message and a few buttons. It also supports 1 or 2 text fields meant for usernames and passwords. Any other uses is risky. It's possible that iOS 7 will bring a whole new `UIAlertView` that causes every misuse to fail miserably. Your best option is to use `UIAlertView` only as intended. If you want a different use, then use a custom widget. There are plenty on github.

Comment: Yup...will consider this. Thanks!

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, I'm not following you. I mentioned the standard (and limited) support for text fields in an alert view. But those are limited and were added in iOS 5.0. I'm not sure you 6.0 feature you mean.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, sorry, I didn't see that. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the use of YLProgressBar added on an alert view cause rejection of my app on app store?

It can. Anything can. Apple has its very own weird and obscure revision system which sometimes seems to lack all logic and contradict itself. Thus, the answer to "can XYZ be a reason for rejection" is always "yes, it potentially can be", and the answer to the question "will my app be approved if I don't do ABC for which another app was rejected?" is "maybe not, maybe yes".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was searching for a document (or anything) which explains these things as some questions on SO has been answered to use this approach. Also Apple doesn't seem to reject apps which use an activity indicator on an alert view. Can you provide anything?

Comment: @Yogi The problem is exactly that Apple can do anything. There are indeed some guidelines which tell you when your app will likely be rejected ([App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html)), but again, you can **never** be sure.